# sudo: react-scripts: command not found

Tags: reactjs, linux, port, sudo, react-scripts

I'm currently trying to run my react app on port 80, and to do that I'm adding a react script such that `"npm start"` runs `"sudo PORT=80 react-scripts start"`. For some reason, I get this error: sudo: react-scripts: command not found. When I run this on port 8080 without sudo, it works perfectly. I also installed react-scripts with sudo but it still errors. Any ideas.

Comment: Why do you need to run as root?

Comment: @Benjamin so i can run on port 80

Comment: elevated permissions are required to listen on ports lower than 1024.  the real question is why :80 is required in the first place.

Comment: @DanO I want port 80 so i can google it without having to append the port number at the end since it looks ugly.

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with `npm` ... is it installed system-wide in your case, are the scripts in the `$PATH`? If no - are you executing `npm start` from within the directory you're in? In that case (and if `$PWD` *aka* `.` is not in your `PATH` either) you'll need to prepend `react-scripts` with `./` ...